# Making backspace work consistently across multiple Unices with xterm

Tags: linux, solaris, aix, tty, xterm

I'm working at a company that uses three different Unices (Linux, Solaris and AIX) all with the same home directories/etc. They all use GNU coreutils (thankfully!), but it's still "interesting" trying to work around various issues. We connect to them by running an X server (Exceed On Demand) on our (Windows) desktops and using xterm, or `ssh`ing from another machine from an existing xterm window (there are other methods too but I don't currently use them so I'll leave them out for now).

In particular, I had issues on Solaris with the backspace key. It would work in bash but just print ^H in some other applications (especially readline-based things).

I'm currently using the solution of having `stty erase ^H` in my `~/.profile` and the following in my `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
*VT100.Translations: #override \
              <Key>BackSpace: string(0x08)\n
```

This seems to work most of the time but is perhaps not desirable since I'm explicitly setting the backspace key to something that might not be the default/preferred on each platform. In particular, I often get messages when using `reset` reminding me that I've set erase to ^H, and very occasionally through a series of circumstances that I haven't yet been able to figure out everything breaks again; perhaps things will work in readline-based apps but not in bash; and I'll have to type `reset` to get everything back to normal.

These issues lead me to believe that this might not be the preferred way of doing this. Does anyone have any improvement over this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Some applications are hardcoded to expect a given erase character, and there's not much you can do with those.

But addressing the comment

> I'm more wondering if I should be doing something else to try to get the backspace sent my xterm to match the default backspace expected by the TTY device.

you *could* set the [ptyInitialErase](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:ptyInitialErase) resource:

> If "true", xterm will use the pseudo-terminal's sense of the
>   stty erase value.  If "false", xterm will set the stty erase
>   value to match its own configuration, using the kb string from
>   the termcap entry as a reference, if available.  In either
>   case, the result is applied to the **`TERMCAP`** variable which xterm
>   sets.
>
> See also the [ttyModes](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:ttyModes) resource, which may override this.  The
>   default is "False".

But for making `xterm` act consistently, `ttyModes` works.  Keep in mind that changing `stty` only tells the system what to expect.  You can change the behavior of the *backarrow* (*backspace*) key using the [ackarrowKey](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:backarrowKey) resource:

> Specifies whether the *backarrow* key transmits a backspace (8)
>   or delete (127) character.  This corresponds to the **`DECBKM`**
>   control sequence.  A "true" value specifies backspace.  The
>   default is "True".  Pressing the control key toggles this
>   behavior.

Comment: I set ptyInitialErase and got rid of all stty commands that I could find, but I still get issues on Solaris. I have no ttyModes or VT100.Translations in my .Xdefaults any more, and I don't think there are any stty commands left. The output of stty on Sun shows erase as ^?, but if I type cat (in order to use the system's line discipline), I get ^H appearing on my terminal when I press backspace.